# FluentNHibernate: Invalid object name on SaveOrUpdate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to get FluentNHibernate up and running.

When I try to add a entity object to the db I get "invalid object name 'Recipe' error in the inner exception and this the main exception

could not insert: [OurRecipes.Domain.Recipe][SQL: INSERT INTO Recipe (EnteredByID, ModifiedOn, Method, PrepTime, CookTime, RecipeTitle) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]

This is how i am configuring it.

```
public static ISessionFactory Create()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
            .ConnectionString(c => c.Is("Server=(local);initial catalog=OurRecipesDB;Integrated Security=SSPI")))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Recipe>())
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

This is my first go at this so....

It doesn't seem to recognise 'Recipe' class in my domain project even though
this configuration runs with no errors .

This the code where I get the error on the SaveOrUpdate line.

```
        var factory = SessionFactoryCreator.Create();

        using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
        {

            Recipe rec = new Recipe();
            rec.RecipeTitle = "test";
            rec.Method = "test";
            rec.PrepTime = 10;
            rec.CookTime = 20;
            rec.EnteredByID = 1;
            rec.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;

            session.SaveOrUpdate(rec);
```

}

EDIT: Sorry guys the SQL table name is Recipes.....Well its late here!

Answer (score 2):

What's your mapping for Recipe look like? My bet is that you didn't define the table name. Your mapping class should look something like:

```
public class RecipeMap : ClassMap<Recipe>
{
    public RecipeMap()
    {
        SchemaIs("dbo");
        WithTable("Recipes");
        [... additional mappings ...]
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed a similar problem I had. Thanks!